# Quartz 2D stroke alignment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawing, path, quartz-2d

Is it possible to adjust the alignment, from the default centered, of a stroke when using kCGPathFillStroke as the drawing mode?

For example, when drawing a closed path using:

```
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

The stroke lies 50% outside/50% inside the drawn path. The stroke color has a non-opaque alpha so the net effect is undesirable. I want the stroke to lie either all inside or outside.

The only potential way I see of doing this is to rebuild the path, contracted by 50% of the stroke width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct.  Adjust the path's position.